# How to work with nopCommerce to create Plugins like create a coupon code?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce-3.90

I want to create a plugin which generate the coupon code and i want to learn about plugins in deep so please recommend me that from where i'll learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can learn from their official website

[Click Here for learning NopCommerce](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Developers+guide)

And coupon code generate you have to create a plugin which can be configured from admin side.

Hope this could be helpful